# How to get Unique values from json using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing

Response code :
In this response eid is repeated, but I want to dispaly only once.

```
{"response": [
        {
            "sid": 1,
            "eid": "AA",
            "ename": "AA11"
          },{
            "sid": 2,
            "eid": "AA",
            "ename": "AA11"
          }
    ],
    "status": "success"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **`unique`** filter from **`AngularUI`**

```
<p ng-repeat="x in data.response | unique: 'ename'">{{x.ename}}</p>
```

**DEMO**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="x in data.response | unique: 'ename'">{{x.ename}}</p>
<script>
//App declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.filters']);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.data = {"response": [
        {
            "sid": 1,
            "eid": "AA",
            "ename": "AA11"
          },{
            "sid": 2,
            "eid": "AA",
            "ename": "AA11"
          }
    ],
    "status": "success"
};
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan got it

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic way. This task should primarily be completed before the response lands the client (on server).

What you can do is make a function which handles the response the way you prefer.

e.g.

```
  //Removes duplicates of eid property
    function getUniqueValues(input) {
        var output = [];

        function existsInOutput(element) {
            return output.map(function(val) {
                return val.eid
            }).includes(element.eid)
        };

        angular.forEach(input,function(val, key) {
            if (!existsInOutput(val)) {
                output.push(val);
            }
        })

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: getting error:  Syntax error on token ">", invalid FunctionExpressionHeader

Comment: `angular.forEach(input,(val, key)` forgot to add `input` attribute. I've edited my answer. I've also made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucs403kL/) for you. Please check

Comment: Thanks for that,  but eclipse is showing error for token ">"

Comment: That's propably because there is no ES6 support. I've switched arrow function back to ES5 syntax. Replace the current version and it should be working.

Comment: Thanks Korte got it